# Does layover for plane change require transit visa in usa?

Tags: visas, usa, transit-visas, layovers, mumbai

I am travelling to Canada on a Migrant Visa. Flying Air India to Newark Liberty & by Air Canada from Newark Liberty to Toronto. Layover for a change of planes being 4hrs 20mins in Newark Liberty Intl. Would I require a US transit Visa for my travel?

Comment: In short, any stop in the USA requires full visa, not just a transit one.

Comment: @Willeke I'm not sure I understand. The US issues many transit visas. [In 2017](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/AnnualReports/FY2017AnnualReport/FY17AnnualReport-TableXVIA.pdf), 19,335 C transit visas and 293,285 C1/D transit/crewmember visas.